# Conditional Probability formula verification

Tags: probability

I was thinking of a situation in probability as explained below:

- Think of event $A$ happening knowing that $B$ occurred
- Think of event $B$ happening knowing that $C$ occurred

  Can we say that $p(A|C) = p(A|B)\cdot p(B|C)$?
- Could anyone help with a mathematical or logical proof, if it is right?

Comment: Don't you have a formula, $P(X\mid Y)=P(X\cap Y)/P(Y)$? What happens when you use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counter-example is sufficient, that the equation does not always hold.

Rolling a fair, 6-sided dice once.

Events:

A: Number 2 or 3 occurs

B: Number 1,2,3 or 4 occurs

C: Number 1,2 or 3 occurs.

Now you can calculate $P(A|C),P(A|B)$ and $P(B|C)$